# A biased coin has probability p of showing heads. What is the probability that 3 heads occur before 3 tails?

Tags: probability

A biased coin has probability p of showing heads. We toss the coin repeatedly until three heads or three tails occur in row. What is the probability that three heads occur before three tails? Cannot understand the previous explanation...
What will be the easiest way to explain it?

Comment: That one seems to be complicated)

Comment: It's a complicated problem.